# How to configure expo updates in bare workflow(how to find my EXUpdatesURL)?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I moved to expo bare workflow using `npx expo prebuild`.

With managed workflow I had already set up expo updates, but now I need additional setup, so I'm following this guide: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-updates/

It seems like most of the configuration was already setup, however adding directory to ios **info.plist** confuses me.

```
  <dict>
    <key>EXUpdatesCheckOnLaunch</key>
    <string>ALWAYS</string>
    <key>EXUpdatesEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EXUpdatesLaunchWaitMs</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>EXUpdatesRuntimeVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
    <string>http://localhost:3000/api/manifest</string>
  </dict>
```

Why does it tell me to setup url as localhost? And how do I actually get the correct url?

It also mentions this:

> When using EAS Update, the EAS CLI will set this URL correctly for the EAS Update service.

So does that mean that I don't need to add url manually myself, if that is the case why does the tutorial ask me to add it to my info.plist?